# Why isn't my child element contained inside the parent?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning CSS and I am having trouble understanding this. I have set both the margin and the padding to 0 (I am also using this CSS reset, so I think this is redundant - http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/).

But for some reason the right side of the child box goes outside the parent. here is my CSS code. `cal` is the parent

```css
#cal {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 30%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#screen {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cal">
  <div id="screen"></div>
</div>
```

And the result, at the right edge...

[image: result]

But then, when I use `box-sizing:border-box`, now the elements line up how I want. I don't understand why

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing. _"...By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added....."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child element is overflowing because you gave it a 100% with plus an additional 5px border

#### Solution 1 - using calc

Removing 5px from the 100%

```css
width: calc(100% - 5px);
```

#### Solution 2 - changing the box-sizing property

Using `box-sizing: border-box;`

You commonly see people changing the `box-sizing` from `content-box` to `border-box`. This basicly makes it so the padding and border are both included in the width property.

Learn more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: hello, thank you I understand now. Thank you for the quick answer too. best